# pip install re2 gives an error

Tags: python, c++, pip, re2

I'm trying to download re2 by the command `pip install re2` and it gives me this:

```
Collecting re2
  Using cached re2-0.2.22.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: re2
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for re2 ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_tul1J/re2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpEx8yE1pip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 're2' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/re2.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/re2.o
  cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
  src/re2.cpp:201:29: fatal error: re2/stringpiece.h: No such file or directory
   #include "re2/stringpiece.h"
                               ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for re2
  Running setup.py clean for re2
Failed to build re2
Installing collected packages: re2
  Running setup.py install for re2 ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_tul1J/re2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qsPvRS-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 're2' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/re2.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/re2.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    src/re2.cpp:201:29: fatal error: re2/stringpiece.h: No such file or directory
     #include "re2/stringpiece.h"
                                 ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_tul1J/re2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qsPvRS-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_tul1J/re2/
```

Why it isn't working? Or should I download re2 by other way?

NOTE: I figured out that re2 must have google's re2 c++ installed already, If that the problem, can you show me how can I install google's re2 c++ and re2 in simple way? I got confused from what they wrote about how to install.

---

After Trying MattDMo's Solution I got this:

```
Collecting re2
  Using cached re2-0.2.22.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: re2
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for re2 ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-azytbM/re2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpxFXFdmpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 're2' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/re2.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/re2.o
  cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
  In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/mutex:35:0,
                   from /usr/local/include/re2/re2.h:184,
                   from src/re2.cpp:202:
  /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
   #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
    ^
  In file included from src/re2.cpp:202:0:
  /usr/local/include/re2/re2.h:734:16: error: ‘once_flag’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
     mutable std::once_flag rprog_once_;
                  ^
  /usr/local/include/re2/re2.h:735:16: error: ‘once_flag’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
     mutable std::once_flag num_captures_once_;
                  ^
  /usr/local/include/re2/re2.h:736:16: error: ‘once_flag’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
     mutable std::once_flag named_groups_once_;
                  ^
  /usr/local/include/re2/re2.h:737:16: error: ‘once_flag’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
     mutable std::once_flag group_names_once_;
                  ^
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for re2
  Running setup.py clean for re2
Failed to build re2
Installing collected packages: re2
  Running setup.py install for re2 ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-azytbM/re2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hKOqNV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 're2' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/re2.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/re2.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/mutex:35:0,
                     from /usr/local/include/re2/re2.h:184,
                     from src/re2.cpp:202:
    /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
     #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
      ^
    In file included from src/re2.cpp:202:0:
    /usr/local/include/re2/re2.h:734:16: error: ‘once_flag’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
       mutable std::once_flag rprog_once_;
                    ^
    /usr/local/include/re2/re2.h:735:16: error: ‘once_flag’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
       mutable std::once_flag num_captures_once_;
                    ^
    /usr/local/include/re2/re2.h:736:16: error: ‘once_flag’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
       mutable std::once_flag named_groups_once_;
                    ^
    /usr/local/include/re2/re2.h:737:16: error: ‘once_flag’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
       mutable std::once_flag group_names_once_;
                    ^
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-azytbM/re2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hKOqNV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-azytbM/re2/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is clone the [`libre2`](https://github.com/google/re2) Github repo along with the [`pyre2`](https://github.com/axiak/pyre2) Github repo (as the version on PyPI available to `pip` has errors in the code), build and install `libre2` first, then build and install `pyre2`.

1. Start your favorite terminal app.
2. Make `src` directory in your `$HOME` for storing source code:

   ```sh
   mkdir ~/src
   ```
3. Enter `src` dir:

   ```sh
   cd ~/src
   ```
4. Clone repo (assuming you have `git` installed):

   ```sh
   git clone https://github.com/google/re2.git
   ```
5. Enter `re2` dir:

   ```sh
   cd re2
   ```
6. Make:

   ```sh
   make
   ```
7. Assuming no errors, make install:

   ```sh
   sudo make install
   ```
8. Clone [`pyre2`](https://github.com/axiak/pyre2) github repo

   ```sh
   git clone https://github.com/axiak/pyre2.git ~/src/pyre2
   ```
9. Switch to repo's directory:

   ```sh
   cd ~/src/pyre2
   ```
10. Build:

    ```sh
    python setup.py build
    ```
11. Install:

    ```sh
    sudo python setup.py install
    ```

Comment: Everything works except 8, it gives me that red text `Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-azytbM/re2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hKOqNV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-azytbM/re2/
` 
Also I think there's more error messages but it too long for comment.

Comment: @johndoe_asking I've tried building it myself on Ubuntu 16.04, and I'm running into the same errors as you. However, please see my updated answer. The release of `pyre2` on PyPI is from May 2015, however its github repo was last updated about 2 months ago. If you clone the repo and build from there, it should work, with some warnings that you can ignore. At least, it worked for me :)

Comment: The question is, if `pyre2` is valid as `re` for using adblockparser.
The reason that I need `re2` it because in `adblockparser`, the use of it can make the filter work very much faster than the regular `re`.
Anyway, you helped me a lot! Thanks and keep up the good work!

Answer (score 8):

If you are on ubuntu, 
`sudo apt-get install libre2-dev` is required prior to calling

```
pip install re2
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue.
For me the issue was that the `bash_profile` file was not properly configured.

To solve this problem:

Install `jdk`

Open `~/.bash_profile` in any text editor or use `vim ~/.bash_profile` command

and add:

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

Open a Terminal and run the source command to apply the changes:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

After this install `re2` using `pip`

`pip install re2`

Answer (score 0):

Since the package `re2` is not maintained anymore, you can use Facebook's pyre2 packages and don't need to change any code.  You can use the package:

```
pip install pyre2
```

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/pyre2